# Change Existing Macro to Print to PDF instead

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, macros

I am new to VBA and do not know how to accomplish what I would like.

Can someone tell me how to make the below macro print to PDF instead of the default printer?

```
Sub PRINTMULTIPACKS()
'
' PRINTMULTIPACKS Macro
'

'
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
ActiveSheet.Range("$C$13:$D$22").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
Sheets("EXPORT TO VENDOR MULTIPLE AREAS").Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$11:$AD$261").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>"
Sheets("FIXTURE SCHEDULE").Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$S$874").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="<>"

Sheets("COVER MULTIPLE AREAS").Select
Range("D10").Select
Sheets(Array("COVER MULTIPLE AREAS", "EXPORT TO VENDOR MULTIPLE AREAS")).Select
Sheets("COVER MULTIPLE AREAS").Activate
ExecuteExcel4Macro "PRINT(1,,,1,,,,,,,,2,,,TRUE,,FALSE)"
Sheets("FIXTURE SCHEDULE").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$S$874").AutoFilter Field:=17
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFiltering:=True

Sheets("EXPORT TO VENDOR MULTIPLE AREAS").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$11:$AD$261").AutoFilter Field:=3
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFiltering:=True
Sheets("COVER MULTIPLE AREAS").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$C$13:$D$22").AutoFilter Field:=1
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFiltering:=True
Range("C10").Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can just save as PDF depending on the version of Excel you are using.

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\sample\Documents\mySheet.pdf", Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Whereby `C:\Users..` is the path and file name where you wish to save.